# How to know app is about to kill in iOS4.x?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

I have an app with locationServices on in background. and have some back ground handle code also.
All I want that when user double click the home button and kill my app I should get notify.There is no application delegate method that is called every time (100%). though the method `applicationWillTerminate:` according to apple will be called on terminating the app but it is called in very rare cases ( 5 times in 100).
Does any body has some idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found a very nice observation, that if your App is running some code in background and user tries to kill it the method `applicationWillTerminate` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider implementing **applicationDidEnterBackground:** method? [The doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW20) says that, "*In iOS 4.0 and later, this method is called instead of the applicationWillTerminate: method when the user quits an application that supports background execution*".

Comment: I have some task in background so `applicationDidEnterBackground` is not of my use... when app is killed i just want to turn off significantLocationServices off\

Answer (score 0):

When an app is hidden using the home key, the operating system will suspend it in memory. When this happens, `applicationDidEnterBackground:` is called. If, at that point, the system decides it needs memory, it will start close apps that are in the background. Sometimes, your app will be on that "hit list". When your app is killed, it is removed from memory completely, just after the `pplicationWillTerminate:` method is called. The method doesn't get called all the time because sometimes, iOS doesn't *need* the memory and so it won't actually terminate your app, but rather it will suspend it.